# Refresh entire "window"...!

Tags: javascript, html

I need to refresh a particular page say every 2 mins. But, only the `<iframe>` within it gets 
refreshed. I tried: `window.location`, `location.href` and so on. I need to pass new parameters every time and reload the page. So, think, `.reload` might not work. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to access the parent:

```
    parent.location.href = 'blah.html'
```

Answer (score 1):

have you tried:

```
document.location.reload(true)
```

or

```
parent.document.location.reload(true);
```